# Cookie dynamic redirect

Tags: php, redirect, cookies

I have a landing page, that sets a cookie whenever a user enters the page. If this cookie is set, it redirects the user to my homepage. The problem is that if my user wants to enter the landing page again and they already have this cookie set, it will automatically redirect them to the homepage. My domain will be set on the landing page, meaning that every time a user enters my site they will see this page.

Is there a way to dynamically allow access to the landing page with the cookie? My users should be able to enter the landing page at will; however I also want the users to be directed to my homepage if they are directly entering my website.

Here's my code:

PHP:

```
<?php
    $time = time() + (60 * 60 * 24);

    if (isset($_COOKIE['landing'])) {
        header('Location: home.php');
    } else {
        setcookie("landing", true, $time);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could use a query parameter, eg. `index.php?noredirect=1`, and in your script:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['landing']) && $_GET['noredirect'] != 1) {
    header('Location: home.php');
} else if(!isset($_COOKIE['landing'])) {
    setcookie('landing', true, $time);
}
```

Now if you append `?noredirect=1` to the url, the user will not be redirected, but by default they will (if the cookie is set).

Answer (score 0):

You need to know if the user wants to stay or not. So you will have to set a variable or something like this.

```
if ( isset( $_COOKIE['landing'] ) && !$user_wants_to_stay ) {
    header( "Location: home.php" ); 
} else {
    ...
}
```

You could use the session or a second cookie which will be set via javascript or simply a get variable in the URL